# Google Sheets Importrange statement in SWITCH

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, switch-statement, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I'm using the `importdata` statement inside in `Switch` condition and it does not return anything nor give an error.

My formula:

```
=SWITCH(C5,"Desired Value",IMPORTRANGE("url to the google spreadsheet", "MyTab!A:E"),C5,"Another Value","Another Value Output")
```

So when it's "Desired Value" is prints nothing. 
If I write a separate `IMPORTRANGE` without `SWITCH` it works fine.

EDIT:

**Example**

Source File (from what I'm importing) [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19csOm3txsZ-RAUiDYbEJLmWUsm5b-Qk9vkMMdJZ6CqM/) and the file with SWITCH statement [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1keXBk9xWmqhXzO4xZGsBkpFTyaLMVNq3PTJ8EN-3yO4)

Comment: Hey! Source File (from what I'm importing) - [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19csOm3txsZ-RAUiDYbEJLmWUsm5b-Qk9vkMMdJZ6CqM) and the file with SWITCH statement [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1keXBk9xWmqhXzO4xZGsBkpFTyaLMVNq3PTJ8EN-3yO4)

Comment: Just tried it once again and it looks like it simply returns the value into only one cell. That's why in my previous attept I haven't seen any error as the title cell was empty. So now the problem is howe to make SWITCH(IMPORTRANGE)) to return multiple cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drop the **`SWITCH`** and use **`IF`** like:

```
=IF(B1="Tab1", IMPORTRANGE("19csOm3txsZ-RAUiDYbEJLmWUsm5b-Qk9vkMMdJZ6CqM", "TAB1!A1:A19"),
 IF(B1="Tab2", IMPORTRANGE("19csOm3txsZ-RAUiDYbEJLmWUsm5b-Qk9vkMMdJZ6CqM", "TAB2!A1:A19"), ))
```

[image: 0]